# Performance of Linux OS on disk partition vs dedicated disk

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partition

I would like to dual boot Ubuntu on my Windows PC workstation with two 1TB ssds. I use Windows for gaming and video editing, and I would like to use Ubuntu for programming and project development. I've tried VMs, and I decided I want to run linux on bare metal in order to take advantage of my computer's hardware. My problem is I do not know how much performance would differ if I installed the OS on a partition of my disk instead of using the whole disk. I do not necessarily want to dedicate an entire TB for my linux boot, but I would if performance would be considerably better on a dedicated disk. Are there any drawbacks about booting Ubuntu on a partition that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance downside to running anything from any position on an SSD. An SSD has no seek time, so it makes no difference if the important parts you want to read it write are at the beginning, end or middle of an SSD.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve decided to go with a partition and it runs great!

Answer (score 0):

Once the kernel is loaded and takes control, there isn't a significant performance difference between reading/writing a filesystem that spans a whole disk device without a partition compared to reading/writing a filesystem that spans the part of a disk that's delimited by a partition.